# Visual Studio Code Infinitest equivalent

Tags: eclipse, unit-tests, visual-studio-code

If I want to do TDD, I can do it easily in eclipse using Infinitest and JUnit4. Now I need to use VS Code and I would like to have my tests running every time I change my code, like Infinitest does in eclipse.

Are there any existing plugins that can do this?